# Como usar tiles na Unity 5?

Tags: c#, unity3d, jogos, unity-5, 2d

Estou com um grande problema. Estou fazendo um RPG e usando tilesets com os tiles nas dimensões 32x32 para todos os gráficos do jogo, mas a unity não tem suporte para tilemaps. Já procurei por plugins e "gambiarras" mas nenhum funcionou, apenas um aparenta funcionar e adivinha... é pago!

Preciso que o meu player se mova **SEMPRE de 1 em 1 tile** assim como no RPG maker MV. Eu faria o jogo inteiro no RMMV mas eu gosto de liberdade para programar e não ficar clicando em botões para criar eventos. Foi por isso que fui pra unity. A documentação do RMMV é horrível e javascript é bem confuso às vezes.

Como faço para contornar o problema? Tem alguma maneira simples de resolver?

Eis o meu código:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public enum PlayerAnimatioState {
    WALK_UP     = 1,
    WALK_RIGHT  = 2,
    WALK_DOWN   = 3,
    WALK_LEFT   = 4,
    IDLE_UP     = 5,
    IDLE_RIGHT  = 6,
    IDLE_DOWN   = 7,
    IDLE_LEFT   = 8,
}

public class PlayerBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {

    private Animator animator;
    private Vector3 directionUp;
    private Vector3 directionDown;
    private Vector3 directionLeft;
    private Vector3 directionRight;

    public PlayerAnimatioState initialState;
    public PlayerAnimatioState animState;
    public float velocity;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
        initialState = PlayerAnimatioState.IDLE_UP;
        animState = initialState;
        animator.SetInteger ("PlayerAnimatorState", (int)animState);
        velocity = 1.5f;
        directionUp = new Vector3 (0, 1);
        directionDown = new Vector3 (0, -1);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.W)) {
            animState = PlayerAnimatioState.WALK_UP;
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.A)) {
            animState = PlayerAnimatioState.WALK_LEFT;
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.S)) {
            animState = PlayerAnimatioState.WALK_DOWN;
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.D)) {
            animState = PlayerAnimatioState.WALK_RIGHT;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.W)) {
            animState = PlayerAnimatioState.IDLE_UP;
        } if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.A)) {
            animState = PlayerAnimatioState.IDLE_LEFT;
        } if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.S)) {
            animState = PlayerAnimatioState.IDLE_DOWN;
        } if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.D)) {
            animState = PlayerAnimatioState.IDLE_RIGHT;
        }
        animator.SetInteger ("PlayerAnimatorState", (int)animState);
        Move ();
    }

    void Move() {
        Vector3 currentPosition = transform.position;
        switch (animState) {
        case PlayerAnimatioState.WALK_UP:
            currentPosition.y += velocity * Time.deltaTime;
            break;
        case PlayerAnimatioState.WALK_DOWN:
            currentPosition.y -= velocity * Time.deltaTime;
            break;
        case PlayerAnimatioState.WALK_LEFT:
            currentPosition.x -= velocity * Time.deltaTime;
            break;
        case PlayerAnimatioState.WALK_RIGHT:
            currentPosition.x += velocity * Time.deltaTime;
            break;
        }
        transform.position = currentPosition;
    }

}
```

Dessa maneira o player não anda uma quantidade fixa, o jogador que escolhe quando parar. Eu queria um esquema de movimentação parecido com o Pokémon Ruby de GBA.

---

**EDITADO**

A resposta do Victor foi de enorme ajuda. Já tenho 90% do que preciso, só que ainda não estou totalmente satisfeito com ela. Suponha que o player esteja parado olhando para cima e eu aperte A (esquerda). Se eu fizer isso ele vai se **mover** para a esquerda, eu queria que ele só se **virasse** para a esquerda. A mesma lógica para as outras opções. Eu apaguei algumas coisas do seu código porque são desnecessárias pro meu projeto, mas guardei para outros futuros.

Obs: o `enum` que ele criou tem a mesma função das opções 5, 6, 7 e 8 do meu.

Eis o meu código editado após incorporar as ideias da resposta dele:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public enum PlayerAnimationState {
    WALK_UP     = 1,
    WALK_RIGHT  = 2,
    WALK_DOWN   = 3,
    WALK_LEFT   = 4,
    IDLE_UP     = 5,
    IDLE_RIGHT  = 6,
    IDLE_DOWN   = 7,
    IDLE_LEFT   = 8
}

public class PlayerMovementBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {
    public Vector3 destino;
    private Animator animator;
    public PlayerAnimationState animState;
    public float velocity;
    public int tileWidth;
    public int tileHeight;

    void Start() {
        animState = PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_UP;
        destino = transform.position;
        velocity = 3f;
        tileWidth = tileHeight = 1;
        animator = GetComponent&lt;Animator&gt; ();
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        animator.SetInteger (&quot;PlayerAnimatorState&quot;, (int)animState);
        EscolherMovimento();
        Move();
    }

    void EscolherMovimento() {
        if (Movendo()) return;

        switch (animState) {
        case PlayerAnimationState.WALK_UP:
            animState = PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_UP;
            break;
        case PlayerAnimationState.WALK_DOWN:
            animState = PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_DOWN;
            break;
        case PlayerAnimationState.WALK_LEFT:
            animState = PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_LEFT;
            break;
        case PlayerAnimationState.WALK_RIGHT:
            animState = PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_RIGHT;
            break;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
            destino.y += tileHeight;
        } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
            destino.x -= tileWidth;
        } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
            destino.y -= tileHeight;
        } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {
            destino.x += tileWidth;
        }
    }

    void Move() {
        if (!PodeAndar ()) return;
        Vector3 paraPercorrer = destino - transform.position;
        Vector3 passo = paraPercorrer.normalized * velocity * Time.deltaTime;
        if (paraPercorrer.magnitude &lt;= passo.magnitude) {
            transform.position = destino;
        } else {
            transform.position += passo;
        }
        if (passo.x &lt; 0 &amp;&amp; Mathf.Abs(passo.x) &gt; Mathf.Abs(passo.y)) animState = PlayerAnimationState.WALK_LEFT;
        if (passo.x &gt; 0 &amp;&amp; Mathf.Abs(passo.x) &gt; Mathf.Abs(passo.y)) animState = PlayerAnimationState.WALK_RIGHT;
        if (passo.y &lt; 0 &amp;&amp; Mathf.Abs(passo.x) &lt;= Mathf.Abs(passo.y)) animState = PlayerAnimationState.WALK_DOWN;
        if (passo.y &gt; 0 &amp;&amp; Mathf.Abs(passo.x) &lt;= Mathf.Abs(passo.y)) animState = PlayerAnimationState.WALK_UP;
    }

    bool Movendo() {
        return transform.position != destino;
    }

    bool PodeAndar() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sem olhar o seu código, fica difícil de te ajudar. De qualquer forma, alterar o `transform.position` do seu player não resolveria?

Comment: Pergunta editada

Comment: Fico surpreso com os 3 votos negativos nesta pergunta. Eu particularmente, acredito que está é uma pergunta muito boa e não merecia esses votos negativos.

Comment: Me questiono a mesma cosia.

Comment: Olá Michael. Bem vindo ao SOPT. Este site **não é um fórum**. Você não deve ficar editando a pergunta para perguntar outra coisa assim que tem a resposta de um dos seus problemas. Para isso, abra outra pergunta. Se não fez ainda, não deixe de fazer o [tour] e ler [ask].

Comment: @VictorStafusa talvez o problema tenha sido o que o Luiz Vieira disse, a pergunta acabou virando bagunça, ou seja, a ideia dela é boa, mas a forma colocada ficou atrapalhada e só uma pessoa com muita vontade de responder poderia fazê-lo. Há quem ache que esse tipo de pergunta não deva ser incentivada, não pelo conteúdo, mas pela forma que vai contra a filosofia básica do site. Então o negativo pode ter sido dado subjetiva e colateralmente ao conteúdo dela.

Comment: @bigown Bem observado. Tomarei mais cuidado da próxima vez.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que a solução é você manter um estado que diga se ele está alinhado com a grid de tiles ou não. Faça o personagem se mover até ele ficar alinhado, e não deixe que nada o interrompa enquanto isso não acontecer. Tão logo ele se alinhe, interrompa o movimento.

Acho que seria isso:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public enum PlayerAnimationState {
    WALK_UP     = 1,
    WALK_RIGHT  = 2,
    WALK_DOWN   = 3,
    WALK_LEFT   = 4,
    IDLE_UP     = 5,
    IDLE_RIGHT  = 6,
    IDLE_DOWN   = 7,
    IDLE_LEFT   = 8,
}

public enum PlayerDirection {
    UP    = 1,
    RIGHT = 2,
    DOWN  = 3,
    LEFT  = 4,
}

public class PlayerBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {

    private Animator animator;
    private Vector3 destino;

    public PlayerDirection direction;
    public float velocity;
    public int tileWidth;
    public int tileHeight;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        direction = PlayerDirection.UP;
        destino = transform.position;
        animator.SetInteger("PlayerAnimatorState", ((int) direction) + 4);
        velocity = 1.5f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate() {
        EscolherMovimento();
        Move();
        animator.SetInteger("PlayerAnimatorState", ((int) direction) + (Movendo() ? 0 : 4));
    }

    void EscolherMovimento() {
        if (Movendo()) return;
        //destino = transform.position; // Caso você tenha certeza de que sempre já estará alinhado.
        destino = Alinhar(transform.position); // Caso possa estar desalinhado.

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) {
            destino.y += tileHeight;
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) {
            destino.x -= tileWidth;
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)) {
            destino.y -= tileHeight;
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)) {
            destino.x += tileWidth;
        }
    }

    void Move() {
        if (!PodeAndar()) return;
        Vector3 paraPercorrer = destino - transform.position;
        Vector3 passo = paraPercorrer.normalized * velocity * Time.deltaTime;
        if (paraPercorrer.magnitude <= passo.magnitude) {
            transform.position = destino;
        } else {
            transform.position += passo;
        }
        if (passo.x < 0 && Mathf.abs(passo.x) > Mathf.abs(passo.y)) direction = PlayerDirection.LEFT;
        if (passo.x > 0 && Mathf.abs(passo.x) > Mathf.abs(passo.y)) direction = PlayerDirection.RIGHT;
        if (passo.y < 0 && Mathf.abs(passo.x) <= Mathf.abs(passo.y)) direction = PlayerDirection.UP;
        if (passo.y > 0 && Mathf.abs(passo.x) <= Mathf.abs(passo.y)) direction = PlayerDirection.DOWN;
    }

    bool Movendo() {
        return transform.position == destino;
    }

    bool PodeAndar() {
        return true;
    }

    private int TileNumber(float pos, int tileSize) {
        return (int) Mathf.Floor(pos / tileSize);
    }

    private float TileOffset(float pos, int tileSize) {
        // Forma otimizada de pos >= 0 ? pos % tileSize : tileSize - (-pos % tileSize)
        return ((pos % tileSize) + tileSize) % tileSize;
    }

    private Vector3 Alinhar(Vector3 alinhando) {
        return new Vector3(TileNumber(alinhando.x, tileWidth) * tileWidth, TileNumber(alinhando.y, tileHeight) * tileHeight);
    }
}
```

Primeiramente, introduzi as variáveis `tileWidth` e `tileHeight`. Os nomes são autoexplicativos.

Eu também troquei o método `Update` para `FixedUpdate`, que é mais apropriado para a atualização da física e da lógica do jogo, por ser chamado em intervalos de tempo regulares.

Eu também introduzi o método `Movendo()` para saber se ele está se movendo ou não e separei a lógica de leitura do teclado no método `EscolherMovimento()`.

O personagem tem um ponto de destino para o qual ele andará sempre que nele não estiver (esta variável é chamada `destino`). Note que este ponto de destino só será alterado no método `EscolherMovimento()` quando um `KeyDown` for recebido, e que os eventos `KeyDown` só serão aceitos se ele estiver parado (ou seja, sob o ponto de destino). Desta forma, enquanto ele estiver se movendo, ele continuará se movendo até terminar, ignorando qualquer outro `KeyDown` (ele só lerá o estado das teclas quando está parado). Essa nova versão não se importa com o `KeyUp`. Note que isso significa que o destino só será definido quando ele começar a se mover, e não quando ele já estiver se movendo e novos eventos de teclado só poderão ser processados quando este ponto de destino for alcançado e o personagem parar.

O método `Move()` (que alterei bastante) é o responsável por fazer o personagem andar até o destino, fazendo ele dar um passo na direção do destino. O primeiro `if` serve para garantir que ele não ultrapasse a posição de destino em algum passo e também serve para estabilizar a posição dele, anulando a margem de erro dos cálculos com `float` que poderiam fazer ele ficar oscilando a micrômetros de distância da posição de destino sem nunca alcançá-la e parar. Caso o personagem esteja parado já sobre o seu ponto de destino, o método também funciona (mas não fará movimento algum).

O método `Move()` também funciona caso o personagem por algum motivo tenha que se mover na diagonal ou se mover nas três dimensões, ou estiver perseguindo um alvo móvel (no caso de a posição de destino estiver sendo alterada com frequência). Caso a posição de destino seja alterada por meios que não seja o método `EscolherMovimento()`, o método `Move()` deverá continuar funcionando sem nehum tipo de problema. Além disso, a velocidade com que ele se move é a mesma em qualquer direção.

O método `EscolherMovimento()` presume que a posição inicial pode estar desalinhada da grid de tiles na hora de decidir qual é a posição de destino. Se a posição inicial estiver sempre alinhada, você pode alterar a forma como a variável `destino` é calculada tal como mostrado no código comentado (mas se deixar como está, continuará funcionando igual). A posição de destino sempre será definida por este método como uma posição alinhada. Note que o conceito de grid/tile só é importante aqui no método `EscolherMovimento()`, o que significa que o método `Move()` funciona independente da existência de tiles/grids, e portanto o método `Move()` pode ser usada tanto para objetos que tenham que obrigatoriamente estar alinhados à grid de tiles quanto para aqueles que não precisam estar.

O método `Move()` agora também se encarrega por decidir para qual lado o personagem está olhando. Ou para ser mais exato, para qual lado ele acabou de dar um passo. Essa direção é o `direction`, para o qual eu também crei o `enum` `PlayerDirection`. Observe que eu não estou mais usando o `PlayerAnimationState` (que você havia digitado incorretamente como `PlayerAnimatioState`), mas mesmo assim o deixei no código porque acredito que você deve estar utilizando em algum outro lugar. O valor do `PlayerAnimationState` pode ser reconstruído ao obter o valor do `PlayerDirection` e somar-se 4 se o personagem estiver parado. Esse processo foi o que usei para colocar os mesmos valores no `PlayerAnimatorState` que você vinha colocando.

O método `TileNumber` é a que descobre qual é o número do tile no qual o personagem está, onde o primeiro parâmetro é a posição do personagem em alguma dimensão e o segundo é o tamanho do tile nesta dimensão. O método `TileOffset` (que não estou usando, mas que talvez você vá precisar) calcula o quanto que o personagem está deslocado ou desalinhado em relação ao tile no qual ele se encontra.

O cálculo da posição e do deslocamento/desalinhamento tem como base o canto inferior esquerdo de um tile. Caso você precise usar o centro do tile como base, então seria necessário fazer uma alteração nos métodos `TileNumber` e `TileOffset`:

```
    private int TileNumber(float pos, int tileSize) {
        return (int) Mathf.Floor((pos + tileSize / 2) / tileSize);
    }

    private float TileOffset(float pos, int tileSize) {
        return (((pos + tileSize / 2) % tileSize) + tileSize) % tileSize - tileSize / 2;
    }
```

Há um efeito colateral importante a ser mencionado: Se você mudar o valor de `transform.position` de um personagem sem mudar também o `destino`, ele imediatamente começará a andar até o destino. Para isso, é que há o método `PodeAndar()`. A lógica desse método sempre retorna `true`, o que significa que o personagem sempre vai tentar andar em direção ao seu destino. Substitua essa lógica por alguma outra coisa diferente e você poderá controlar quando o personagem pode andar mesmo se não estiver em seu destino ou não.

Note que muito desse código é reutilizável. Para implementar NPCs diversos, basta trocar o funcionamento dos métodos `EscolherMovimento()` e `PodeAndar()`. Os demais métodos são iguais. Com um pouco (só um pouco) de trabalho, você consegue separá-los em componentes (`MonoBehaviour`s) diferentes.

Por fim, um último aviso: Eu não testei isso, então não sei se errei algum detalhezinho bobo. Mas se não for isso daqui que está acima, então é quase isso.

---

**EDITADO**

Após a solução inicial ser postada, considerando o feedback do autor da pergunta, agora é necessário primeiro olhar e depois andar, além de eliminar o que acabou não sendo necessário, eis aqui a minha nova versão:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public enum PlayerAnimationState {
    WALK_UP     = 1,
    WALK_RIGHT  = 2,
    WALK_DOWN   = 3,
    WALK_LEFT   = 4,
    IDLE_UP     = 5,
    IDLE_RIGHT  = 6,
    IDLE_DOWN   = 7,
    IDLE_LEFT   = 8,
}

public class PlayerBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {
    private Vector3 destino;
    private Animator animator;
    private KeyCode precisaSoltar;
    private float horaTeclaPressionada;
    public PlayerAnimationState animState;
    public float velocity;
    public int tileWidth;
    public int tileHeight;

    void Start() {
        precisaSoltar = KeyCode.Space;
        horaTeclaPressionada = Time.fixedTime;
        animState = PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_UP;
        destino = transform.position;
        velocity = 3f;
        tileWidth = tileHeight = 1;
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        EscolherMovimento();
        Move();
        animator.SetInteger("PlayerAnimatorState", (int) animState);
    }

    private void Parar() {
        switch (animState) {
        case PlayerAnimationState.WALK_UP:
            animState = PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_UP;
            break;
        case PlayerAnimationState.WALK_DOWN:
            animState = PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_DOWN;
            break;
        case PlayerAnimationState.WALK_LEFT:
            animState = PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_LEFT;
            break;
        case PlayerAnimationState.WALK_RIGHT:
            animState = PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_RIGHT;
            break;
        }
    }

    void EscolherMovimento() {
        bool m = Movendo();
        if (!m) Parar();
        if (precisaSoltar != KeyCode.Space && Input.GetKey(precisaSoltar) && Time.fixedtime - horaTeclaPressionada < 1.0f) return;
        precisaSoltar = KeyCode.Space;
        if (!m) LerTeclado();
    }

    void LerTeclado() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && animState != PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_UP) {
            animState = PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_UP;
            precisaSoltar = KeyCode.W;
        } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && animState == PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_UP) {
            destino.y += tileHeight;
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && animState != PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_LEFT) {
            animState = PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_LEFT;
            precisaSoltar = KeyCode.A;
        } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && animState == PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_LEFT) {
            destino.x -= tileWidth;
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) && animState != PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_DOWN) {
            animState = PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_DOWN;
            precisaSoltar = KeyCode.S;
        } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && animState == PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_DOWN) {
            destino.y -= tileHeight;
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) && animState != PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_RIGHT) {
            animState = PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_RIGHT;
            precisaSoltar = KeyCode.D;
        } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && animState == PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_RIGHT) {
            destino.x += tileWidth;
        }

        if (precisaSoltar != KeyCode.Space) horaTeclaPressionada = Time.fixedTime;
    }

    void Move() {
        if (!PodeAndar()) return;
        Vector3 paraPercorrer = destino - transform.position;
        Vector3 passo = paraPercorrer.normalized * velocity * Time.deltaTime;
        if (paraPercorrer.magnitude <= passo.magnitude) {
            transform.position = destino;
        } else {
            transform.position += passo;
        }
        if (passo.x < 0 && Mathf.abs(passo.x) > Mathf.abs(passo.y)) direction = PlayerAnimationState.WALK_LEFT;
        if (passo.x > 0 && Mathf.abs(passo.x) > Mathf.abs(passo.y)) direction = PlayerAnimationState.WALK_RIGHT;
        if (passo.y < 0 && Mathf.abs(passo.x) <= Mathf.abs(passo.y)) direction = PlayerAnimationState.WALK_UP;
        if (passo.y > 0 && Mathf.abs(passo.x) <= Mathf.abs(passo.y)) direction = PlayerAnimationState.WALK_DOWN;
    }

    bool Movendo() {
        return transform.position == destino;
    }

    bool PodeAndar() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

A grande diferença está nos `if`s que leem o input. Eles têm a seguinte forma:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.TECLA) && animState != PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_DIRECAO) {
    animState = PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_DIRECAO;
    precisaSoltar = KeyCode.TECLA;
} else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.TECLA) && animState == PlayerAnimationState.IDLE_DIRECAO) {
    destino.eixo -= tileMedida;
}
```

Observe que ele usa ora o `GetKeyDown` e ora o `GetKey`. O primeiro `if` deste bloco significa que se a tecla acabou de ser pressionada e o personagem não estiver olhando para a direção correspondente, então ele olhará e marca que para algo acontecer depois, a tecla pressionada precisará ser primeiramente solta. O segundo `if` significa que se a tecla está pressionada (não importando a quanto tempo, possivelmente de forma contínua) e o personagem já estava olhando na direção correta, então ele continua.

Isso por si só não funcionaria na hora de virar, pois ao apertar uma tecla ele viraria e começaria a andar imediatamente. É aí que entram as variáveis `precisaSoltar` e `horaTeclaPressionada`. Elas servem para rastrear qual tecla deve ser solta antes de poder começar a andar (é a mesma tecla usada para virar). Se o usuário não soltá-la dentro de um segundo, o personagem deve começar a nadr mesmo assim. Se o usuário soltar e apertar novamente, ele começará a andar.

Esse trecho:

```
        if (precisaSoltar != KeyCode.Space && Input.GetKey(precisaSoltar) && Time.fixedtime - horaTeclaPressionada < 1.0f) return;
        precisaSoltar = KeyCode.Space;
```

Isso verifica se a tecla que deve ser solta foi de fato solta ou se ela foi mantida pressionada por mais de um segundo. A tecla de espaço é usada para denotar o caso em que nenhuma tecla precisa ser solta. Já esse trecho:

```
        if (precisaSoltar != KeyCode.Space) horaTeclaPressionada = Time.fixedTime;
```

Serve para registrar quando a tecla foi pressionada de forma que seja possível contar-se um segundo a partir desse momento.

Noto que você retirou o `destino = Alinhar(transform.position);`. Isso é algo válido de se fazer e funciona, mas agora você vai ter que ter mais cuidado ao controlar o destino do personagem, pois você não tem mais algo que força o alinhamento do destino na grid de tiles caso por algum motivo ele acabe permanecendo parado em uma posição desalinhada. Por outro lado, dependendo do que você esteja fazendo, isso pode até ser algo inevitável e/ou desejável e/ou intencional.

Há mais um último detalhe. Acho que o `animator.SetInteger("PlayerAnimatorState", (int) animState);` deveria ficar no fim do método `FixedUpdate()`, e não no começo. Caso contrário, ele vai setar um valor que estará desatualizado quando a execução deste método for finalizada.

Comment: Eu respondi minha própria pergunta porque precisei colocar mais código e se eu editasse minha pergunta ia ficar muito grande. Dá uma conferida por favor. Muitíssimo obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @MichaelPacheco Ok, já estou pensando na solução.

Comment: Não seu se você viu mas eu troquei o `GetKeyDown` por `GetKey` para aceitar um movimento contínuo. Acho que isso influencia na lógica.

Comment: @MichaelPacheco Solução revisada.

Comment: Na sua nova lógica eu precisaria soltar a tecla para continuar o movimento. Se o player estiver parado olhando para cima e eu apertar para baixo (S) e segurar, ele deve andar para baixo, e não apenas olha para baixo e parar esperando eu soltar o S e depois apertá-lo de novo para que ele ande. Mas obrigado por tentar ajudar.

Comment: @MichaelPacheco Segurar o S por mais de um segundo não deu certo?

Comment: Não, a lógica está dando erro. Se você começa virado para cima e segura o A (esquerda) ele vira para a esquerda, espera um segundo e anda para a esquerda. Se você parar e segurar para direita, ele vira para a direita e depois de um segundo anda para a esquerda kkkk.

Comment: @MichaelPacheco Em algum momento você apertou duas teclas simultaneamente?

Comment: Não, em momento algum.

Comment: @MichaelPacheco Acho que é porque ele não estava verificando se a tecla havia sido solta enquanto ele estava andando, só quando tinha parado. Editei a resposta mais uma vez.

Comment: O erro permanece. Acho que esse tempo de resposta não é uma boa solução. O jogador com certeza vai ficar irritado.

Comment: @MichaelPacheco Se o jogador tiver que obrigatoriamente apertar a tecla duas vezes para começar a andar, você acha que ele ficaria irritado?

Comment: @MichaelPacheco Achei, foi erro de digitação. Eu havia errado um sinal. Coloquei um `-` na direita ao invés de `+`.

Comment: Elaborei uma solução elegante para o problema. Para não bagunçar mais ainda o post eu coloquei o código no pastebin. Achei que você iria querer ver a solução. Mais uma vez muitíssimo obrigado pela sua ajuda. http://pastebin.com/LCkJ9r01