# Como fazer um transform.Translate() suavizado no unity5?

Tags: c#, unity-5

Eu preciso transladar um `GameObject` para um destino qualquer, mas a transição deve ser suave em uma velocidade constante de tal forma que dure o tempo que for passado por parâmetro. Por exemplo:

```
void Move(GameObject obj, Vector3 destination, float durationInMs) {}
```

Essa função deveria transladar `obj` para `destination` em um tempo exato de `durationInMs` milissegundos. Eu tentei fazer isso usando passos ao invés de tepo, mas a precisão fica muito pequena em máquinas com alta taxa de FPS:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SquareMovementBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {
    Vector3 initialPosition;
    Vector3 finalPosition;
    Vector3 currentPosition;
    Vector3 step;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        initialPosition = transform.position;
        finalPosition = new Vector3(10, 0, 0);
        step = finalPosition - initialPosition;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, finalPosition) >= 0.1) // Precisão fraca. Não funciona :/
            transform.Translate (step * Time.deltaTime);
        else
            transform.position = finalPosition;
    }
}
```

Como faço para implementar essa função `Move()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embora a sua pergunta seja bem diferente [dessa sua outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150931/132) (e portanto, não é duplicata), a resposta é essencialmente [a mesma resposta que eu dei lá](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/150968/132). Há apenas um detalhezinho a mais, que é que você deve acrescentar mais algum método a mais para definir ou redefinir o valor dos campos `destino` e `velocity`.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem se é isso que você quer, mas de uma lida em:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html

ou

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html